# Correct Use of Past Perfect Tense in the context

Tags: past-perfect

I have asked so many question about use of Had (Past Perfect) in English sentence. But sometime after I made my concept clear come across some sentence which force me to re think it.

E.g.

https://www.indiatoday.in/pti-feed/story/vajpayee-used-to-listen-to-every-party-when-he-was-pm-mamata-1316493-2018-08-16

"He had come to my residence and I am grateful to him for that. Both families share a very cordial relationship."

Similarly can I use Perfect Tense for below scenario / Context.

One of my colleague came to me to discuss some issue. we discussed it and he left. after 2 days we discussed it with other team member.

To report whatever discussed earlier can I start my conversation as below?

"Mr. Xyz had come to my desk to discussed about xyz issue. We discussed it but now we want a solution from you also."

Whenever I asked this type of questions I was asked to use Simple past instated of past perfect. But when I read similar contexts in past perfect I get confused. Even some of the article I read while reporting use of Simple Past and Past perfect is optional.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

when using the pluperfect you have TWO reference points in the past; that is the key to using it.  In other words, you say something like: "My friend wanted to go to the store, but I had already gone there."
The difference with your example is that you are talking to the other team member about ONE past reference point, so you would say, "Mr. XYZ came to my desk to discuss xyz..."
Now, if you are telling yet another person about the whole scenario with two reference points in the past, you would say, "Mr. XYZ had come to me and then we went to the other team member for his opinion."
Hope this helps.